# LaTeX Document Class

Tags: document-classes

I would like to know which LaTeX document class has been used for the following three papers.

https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/488.pdf

https://eprint.iacr.org/2023/250.pdf

https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/261.pdf

I have seen a lot of papers on Cryptology ePrint Archive which seem to be generated based on the same document class. This question might be ridiculously easy for people who are familiar with LaTeX. I am not familir with Latex. So I would like to know. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome. // I'm quite sure it's the standard class `article` . Usually you can download templates, e.g. for Word or Latex. Didn't see them there. However, probing into the Latex sources on https://www.iacr.org/docs/ reveals a certain pattern ;-)

Comment: I tried the class article before, but it did not work. Maybe I made some mistakes. I will re-try again later. Thank you very much.

Comment: Wishing you success. When you fail, please feel free to raise a new question and post your code with it, so we can help you more specifically. // BTW, do you have a book or two on Latex basics?

Comment: Actually I am not a LaTeX beginner. I wrote more than 50 papers by LaTeX, including a long doctoral thesis. I just am not familiar with LaTeX document classes. Your answer was very helpful. I think I can solve the problem by myself.

Comment: It looks more like standard report.cls to me, with chapters, oneside, and no frontmatter/mainmatter. The margins and title page may be customized a bit.

Comment: Welcome TeX.SE @ishimasa :) As MS-SPO and John said, start trying with article and report standard classes. However, I've found the following but don't how relevant they are: https://github.com/IACR/latex and https://github.com/Cryptosaurus/iacrtrans/ (this later is referenced from [tches](https://tches.iacr.org/index.php/TCHES/submission)/[ches](https://ches.iacr.org/2022/papersubmission.php) and [tosc](https://tosc.iacr.org/Submission) subdomains)

Comment: Also note that for Eurocrypt [2022](https://eurocrypt.iacr.org/2022/papersubmission.php)/[2023](https://eurocrypt.iacr.org/2023/papersubmission.php)/etc. they're using `llncs` with plain page style. Appart that, they seem to use `iacrr` or `iacrtrans` depending on the field/subject.

Answer (score 0):

Some extensions, which fit badly into a comment line.

#### Standard classes

Find [standard classes and their options desribed here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure#Document_classes) . A detailed description of the article classes code is [available on ctan](https://mirror.dogado.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/base/classes.pdf).

#### Document classes similar to article

... are also available on [ctan](https://ctan.org/topic/article-like).

#### A huge collection of document classes

... can also be found on [ctan](https://www.ctan.org/topic/class). But for sure, there are many more out there. E.g. [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/articles) provides many templates, which may or may not be available via ctan as well. See e.g. the entries under Academic Journals.

A template, similar to the links you posted, is also available on [Overleaf; copy from View Source](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/a-simple-article-template/gdsdkccmjnxg).